# How do I get app screen size of a iPad from Qt application

Tags: qt, ipad, qml, screen, qt-creator

How do I get app screen size of a iPad from Qt application

I am developing an application in Qt with screen resolution 1280x542.
And I need to build the application to iPad with all resolutions (up to 12.9 inch).

So, I need to change the application screen size to fit the screen (not full screen) with a radio of my existing screen size. so I am multiplying a radio with the existing size (current iPad screen size 1024x768).

But, issue with the iPad pro(12.9 inch screen). The application not fit to the screen.

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand the problem but, does [`QPaintDevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html) not provide the information you need?

Comment: Using Qt Quick Layouts would probably avoid this issue.